# chrome debugger: continue execution without having to use mouse

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, webkit, web-inspector

When the chrome web inspector has paused due to a debugger breakpoint,

how can one resume execution without using the mouse?

Is there like a

debugger.continue()

I can issue in the console repl

Answer (score 0):

There is no `debugger.continue()` since it is a keyword, but you can disable breakpoints:

[image]

Comment: question mentioned "without using the mouse"

Comment: then you can press Ctrl + F8